# Modify individual instances after instancing on points along a path

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, instances

I've created a pipe bracket which I want to distribute along the pipe(a curve), I'm using geometry nodes to achieve this, and my node tree is shown in the picture below. I want to delete the first and the last pipe brackets, and some brackets in the middle,[image: Geometry Nodes]

Can someone help me? Thx.

Comment: Delete them how? Do you mean you'd like to skip some points?

Answer (score 0):

welcome.
In order to delete points you can use the `index`, some `compare node` and `math node` with a `delete geometry node`… If I understand correctly what you need?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

Instead of deleting instances, it might be more efficient not to spawn these, taking advantage of the *Selection* input socket of the *Instance on Points* node.
To improve readability in the following GN graph, a chain of tests is assembled to tag instances **not** to spawn using *Or* boolean operators. Then the selection mask is defined using the *Not* boolean operator. As examples (from top to bottom):

- The last point is excluded by comparing its *Index* to the number of points recovered with a *Domain Size* node set in *Point Cloud* domain.
- The first point is excluded by comparing its *Index* to 0.
- Three points around the middle are excluded by comparing their distance to the origin of an other object, to a threshold (set to 0.5 here).

[image: GN graph and results]

Resources: [image]